# Looking for code to ask "Please rate this app"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am looking for code to ask the user if they want to rate the app, after they have been using it for X amount of time. I have seen this in some of the big gaming apps.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried to do to solve this problem on your own. We are not here to do your work for you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52101/how-to-respond-to-people-just-asking-for-code-without-any-own-effort

Comment: I have been trying to find this for hours and can't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is widely used for prompting to rate apps.

http://arashpayan.com/blog/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/

Edit:

Getting Started

```
Add the Appirater code into your project 
Add the CFNetwork and SystemConfiguration frameworks to your project 
Call [Appirater appLaunched:YES] at the end of your app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. 
Call [Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES] in your app delegate's applicationWillEnterForeground: method. 
(OPTIONAL) Call [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES] when the user does something 'significant' in the app. 
Finally, set the APPIRATER_APP_ID in Appirater.h to your Apple provided software id.
```

Comment: Im not finding the code easy to implement. Is there a better example you can provide. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the readme instructions on the github? Can't be any simpler than that. Have edited my reply with instructions.

Comment: is the set the APPIRATER_APP_ID in Appirater.h to your Apple provided software id. The com.brandonsdesigngroup.appname

Comment: For the record, there is one more step not pointed out anywhere (that I have seen): change APPIRATER_DEBUG to NO in Appirater.h, or your users will be prompted on every launch instead of after the 30-day, 15-use delay that's intended.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate is also another library to do the same thing.

Comment: How to change the store @Nick Lockwood

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question?

Answer (score 1):

[RMRecurringURLAlert](http://www.binpress.com/app/recurring-uialert-for-appstore-ratings/431) does what you want.